# How to remove Unused CSS From a WordPress Theme?

Tags: plugins, css, performance

I used a premium theme from ThemeForest & Elementor Page Builder.

There are lots of Demo Theme provided by the Main Theme. I used only one. But in my style.css, I am watching 45000 lines of CSS. Maybe I am using 5000 lines & 40000 lines is completely useless or Unused.

Like - from my Main Theme, they are providing 23 various styles of headers. But I am using one & there are 22 unused styles.

So, I really want to get the solution by removing the useless CSS from style.css file.

Here is the Google Pagespeed Insight Report for making sense. [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fweexperto.com%2F).

Please gimme some suggestion to do it smoothly.

Comment: This is one of the many downsides of using a page builder or highly customisable theme. Unfortunately it’s ultimately up to the theme author to handle this, so I suggest speaking to them. Especially as third party themes and plugins are off topic here.

Comment: The upside to WordPress is the low barrier to entry, pretty much anyone can build a site a using intricate multi-purpose themes and a variety of plugins.  The downside to WordPress is the low barrier to entry that relies on intricate multi-purpose themes with a one-size fits all approach and that tend to include the kitchen sink in their code base 'just in case'.  At a certain point when stuff like optimizing the code you're actually loading on a WordPress site becomes mission critical, you have to abandon using multi-purpose themes that were designed to appeal to as many users as possible.

Comment: I know there's plugins out there that optimize and compress CSS/JS from themes and plugins, but I've also seen those plugins break entire sections and functionality of sites because their optimization and minification/clean-up algorithms get something wrong.